# Local TzKT indexer much slower than api.tzkt.io

Tags: query, indexer, tzkt

I have a local version of the TzKT indexer and API (v1.11.1) running for mainnet on a server without any apparent issues. I am running a program that retrieves all transactions in the history of the blockchain in batches of 10K by querying the indexer with the following URL:

`http://[indexer]:5000/v1/operations/transactions?limit=10000&offset=[X]`

Where `[indexer]` is just a placeholder for the real domain (or `localhost` if I use it from the server itself) and `[X]` increases by 10K for each consecutive query.

For initial queries where `offset` is still relatively small, the execution time is below 8 seconds, which I find acceptable. However, when coming into higher values like `offset=10100000` the execution times go up to around 3 minutes, while the same query on https://api.tzkt.io/ takes about 30 seconds. Is there a way to prevent the query times from increasing so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to paginate over the data with a cursor, instead of the `offset`, when it's possible. It will be much faster, because it will enable DB to do index scan, instead of sequential scan over the whole table.

In your case you can use `?id.gt={lastReceivedId}` as a cursor. For example:

- https://api.tzkt.io/v1/operations/transactions?offset=10000000 is executed in **20 sec**, because the DB goes over 10,000,000 rows.
- https://api.tzkt.io/v1/operations/transactions?id.gt=43555760373759 is executed in **50 ms**, because the DB can do index scan by the `Id` column and "jump" to the needed row.

As you can see, there can be multiple ways to get the same data from the API, so if some query seems slow, just try a different approach. A general advice - avoid sequential scan in case of huge tables, and always try to make the DB do index scan.

As for the performance difference between your instance and api.tzkt.io, it's just a matter of 1) hardware setup and 2) DB settings optimization. So, try to improve your hardware setup and try to optimize your DB, according to your hardware and use case.